# Android ListView of videos available on device

Tags: android, listview, android-contentprovider, mediastore

*The below code is not working,App gets closed on launching with "Unfortunately..." error.*

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_media_store_list_view);

    vedio_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vedio_list);

    Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};

    cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);

    title_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE);

    al = new ArrayList<String>();

    showList();
   }

private void showList() {

    while(cursor.moveToNext())
    {
        String title = cursor.getString(title_index);

        al.add(0 , title);
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    cursor.close();

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: please post the logcat

Comment: What is that "unfortunately error"?????

Answer (score 0):

Check if the cursor is good by getting the count and move to the first one on the list :

```
private void showList() {
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   while(cursor.moveToNext())
     {
    String title = cursor.getString(title_index);
    al.add(0 , title);
    aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
     }
 }
cursor.close();
}
```